# DITA for documenting software libraries

Tags: dita

While this is not a question about DITA "programming" I'd still like to ask it within the stackoverflow community where most users would happen to be developers.

Our company uses a combination of Doxygen & MediaWiki to document software libraries (such as [QSchematic](https://github.com/simulton/QSchematic)). We feel like MediaWiki is not a good way of documenting software libraries.

My question: Should I start using DITA to document software libraries? I've spend quite a few hours working with DITA and DITA-OT and I think it's a good solution for documenting software components that the end users directly interacts with (eg. command line tools). However, I'm not quite sure whether DITA is a nice solution to document software libraries. After quite a lot of research it seems like DITA is not widely used by software (library) developers. DITA provides specialization that would allow setting up custom topics for this purpose but as nobody else on the web seems to be doing that I'm wondering whether there's anything fundamentally wrong with using DITA for this purpose.

Comment: You might want to check the [help/on-topic] and [ask], this question is not a good fit for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. So far I've optimized the title of the question.
I looked at the help center. I hoped that this question would fall under the `software tools commonly used by programmers; [...]` category.
Please let me know where I should place this question instead. I couldn't find an exchange community for documentation or similar.

Comment: I believe a more appropriate SE for this question would be [Software Recs](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/). Make sure to read their help center to get a feel for what constitutes a tool request on their site =)

Comment: Markdown and other lightweight markup languages are widely used for software. If you want more structure and are still interested in DITA, look at the Markdown format of Lightweight DITA: https://docs.oasis-open.org/dita/LwDITA/v1.0/cn01/LwDITA-v1.0-cn01.html

Comment: I work for Oxygen XML Editor and we use our own tool to create an user's manual from DITA content. Our DITA content is located on a GitHub account: https://github.com/oxygenxml/userguide and the generated HTML documentation is here: https://www.oxygenxml.com/doc/versions/21.0/ug-editor/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DITA could be a good fit and provides all features you need or could need in the future. Maybe a tool like read-the-docs or Swagger would also fit, but that depends on the documents you want to create, so is difficult to answer without knowing your libraries and content. DITA has the benefit of reuse and flexibility. You can use external code fragments, reuse parts of your reference docs in conceptual topics and task topics giving you the power to achieve anything you could imagine.